# Wikileaks has an unusual robots.txt. What may I crawl?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am going through the process of figuring out how I would write a web crawler for Wikileaks.

When I got to https://wikileaks.org/robots.txt all I can see is what appears to be a bunch of innocuous looking HTML that looks like it might define a home page or something.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a reason why somebody would put this in their robots.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error, probably some server misconfiguration. A good robots.txt is as easy as possible to make sure even the cheapest crawler gets it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Going to crawl on ahead then.

Answer (score 3):

[On 2016-01-03](https://web.archive.org/web/20160103221721/https://wikileaks.org/robots.txt), Wikileaks’ robots.txt was:

> ```
> User-Agent: *
> Disallow: /talk/
> ```

[On 2016-01-05](https://web.archive.org/web/20160105025731/https://wikileaks.org/robots.txt), it was a HTML document served as plain text.

All crawls from the following dates [in 2016](https://web.archive.org/web/20160101000000*/https://wikileaks.org/robots.txt) and [in 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20170101000000*/https://wikileaks.org/robots.txt) seem to show this same invalid content (I only made spot checks).

So, formally speaking, everything is allowed to be crawled now. But as this is obviously an error on their side, it would be polite to honour their last working robots.txt: everything is allowed to be crawled except for URLs with a path starting with `/talk/`.